# How can I tell what version of SharePoint a site is using, from the outside?

Tags: sharepoint

how can I tell what version of SharePoint a site is using, without being able to see the admin panel?

Is there anything, perhaps in the source of the pages, that would give me a clue?

Comment: Unless it has been heavily customised it is usually pretty obvious from the UI, but perhaps you mean a specific version number, rather than WSS/MOSS 2003/7 or Sharepoint 2010 etc?

Comment: @dunxd 2003/2007/2010.  Could you post screenshot examples of the different versions' UI?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I only have one version of SharePoint and it is customised.  You could always just ask the site administrator what version they use, although I think they would be suspicious (as am I) of why you want to know.  Perhaps you can expand your question - people may sit on their hands if they think you are probing sites to discover potential to make mischief :-)

Comment: Well, there's 25 rep in it for someone who can ...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For sites that haven't been customised much, you can tell a lot from the design.

Typical default 2003 site

[image: Typical default 2003 site]

Default 2007 page

[image: Default 2007 page]

2010 page

[image: 2010 page]

2013 page

[image: 2013 page]

The tab style is generally a give-away of the version in use.  If you want to know the sub-version, you'll have to ask the site admin.

*There are probably also some clues in the dress of the corporate drones in the revolting stock images ;-)*

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. :D

Comment: Those pictures won't do any good if the site uses nicely-customized master pages and branding.

Answer (score 25):

You can check the http response headers, e.g., with Firefox's Web Developer toolbar:

Information | View response headers

MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6332

MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4762

Fiddler, used with IE, will expose these headers as well.

- v14 maps to SP 2010 
  v12 maps to MOSS
  2007

[Extensive list here](http://insomniacgeek.com/blog/how-to-determine-the-installed-sharepoint-version/) of minor versions of 2007.

Comment: Under some circumstances, this header does not get updated.  See more here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-mythbusting-the-response-header-contains-the-current-sharepoint-version  I'm currently troubleshooting a case where it is not even after the psconfig he recommends.

Answer (score 13):

You can see it in Chrome's dev tools too (similar to [the Firefox answer](https://serverfault.com/a/213726/123371)):

In Chrome:

- F12 (developer tools)
- Click the "Network" tab
- If there are no entries, refresh the page.
- Select the main "aspx" page in the list of items.
- Expand "Response Headers"
- The value of "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices" is what you're looking for.

There's also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/hplfkkmefamockhligfdcfgfnbcdddbg?hl=en) which makes the process a little easier.

Answer (score 5):

I realize you don't have admin or owner rights, but I'm going to throw this out for the general audience...

If you go to the Site Settings, it will tell you the exact version right at the top of the page.

Comment: I got 12.0.0.6421 - how do I know which year this relates to? Is it sharepoint 2007?

Comment: This does not appear to be true in Sharepoint 2003

Answer (score 5):

Just click on "Help" - it should be right there at the top!

Comment: In Sharepoint 2007, the help page does indeed say it is 2007!

Comment: works in the Mysite but not a corporate customised main page.  +1, thanks!

Comment: This is the Perfect Answer for those who do not have admin rights!

Comment: This works for SharePoint 2010 as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a [little javascript like the examples here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/how-to-detect-the-edition-of-sharepoint-2010-installed/167364#167364).

If you view the page source and see something like this in the html head - with `corev4` in the css link - you'll know it's at least Sharepoint 2010.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=p63%2BuzTeSJc22nVGNZ5zwg%3D%3D"/>
```

## My favourite way

If you take the domain from the url and add this to it: `_vti_pvt/service.cnf` it will send back a page with the version on it.  So, if your site is this one: https://sp.towson.edu/default.aspx then you'd change the url to this: https://sp.towson.edu/_vti_pvt/service.cnf (You can try with both of those links).  However, I tried this trick on [Path to Sharepoint](http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/default.aspx) and I get a login box.

Comment: This is a great method. It works on every server I tried, even when I wasn't logged in, as long as I went all the way down to the root.

Comment: This should be the first thing you try. If this fails then try the other slightly more involved Dev tool ways.